# How to Convert Edn string to Json

Tags: java, json, edn

I have to retrieve data from some site that sends back responses with **edn bodies**. I am trying to convert the sent back **Edn** to **Json** so I can parse it with Jsoup.

I found a [website](http://cljson.com/) that was able to do the conversion, but how do I implement something like this in **java**?

I tried something like this, but it didn't a full job:

```
public static String edmToJson(String edm) {
    String json = edm;
    json = json.replaceFirst("(\\(\\{).*?(}\\))", "1").replace("(", "").replace("})", "").replace("} {", "},{");
    return json;
}
```

Is there a way to do it without using closure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print EDN output in JSON format using Cheshire custom encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331109/how-to-print-edn-output-in-json-format-using-cheshire-custom-encoder)

Comment: @JoSSte I was hoping for a purely java code approach. I don't know anything about closure.

Comment: something like https://github.com/mikera/edn-pojos ?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse EDN data in java by using a library like `edn-java`.

Sample usage:

```java
@Test
public void simpleUsageExample() throws IOException {
    Parseable pbr = Parsers.newParseable("{:x 1, :y 2}");
    Parser p = Parsers.newParser(defaultConfiguration());
    Map<?, ?> m = (Map<?, ?>) p.nextValue(pbr);
    assertEquals(m.get(newKeyword("x")), 1L);
    assertEquals(m.get(newKeyword("y")), 2L);
    assertEquals(Parser.END_OF_INPUT, p.nextValue(pbr));
}
```

Complete docs available at [edn-java](https://github.com/bpsm/edn-java)